# How to install Sally on Mac? How to install libconfig package on Mac OSX

Tags: mac, installation, c++, c

I want to install Sally http://www.mlsec.org/sally/ on MacOSX when I run `./configure`, I get stuck at:

```
No package 'libconfig' found
```

even after installing libconfig through macports.

Can anyone shred some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with how i installed libconfig.

Should have installed using the following command:

```
sudo port install libconfig-hr
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have MacPorts configured to install into '/opt/local' (see `prefix` in `macports/macports.conf`)...

You'll want to check that your `${CPPFLAGS}` contains `-I/opt/local/include` and your `${LDFLAGS}` `-L/opt/local/lib`

Comment: How can I get the installation directory of libconfig that was installed via MacPorts?

Comment: The configuration is running but when I want to make the program I get the following error: input_lines.c:35: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'cfg'
Could it be an architecture problem?

Comment: @mabounassif: You'll have to read the rest of the logfile to understand what's missing.